# general formula for a sequence

Tags: calculus

Find the general formula for $\{2,5,7,12,17,...\}$

I am able to come up with a formula excluding the first 2 terms $a_1=2$, $a_2=5$ and $a_n=2+5(n-2)$ for $n\geq 3$

Comment: [OEIS search](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C7%2C12%2C17)

Comment: Well, you could just define
$$
a_n = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
2~&\text{if}~n=1 \\
5~&\text{if}~n=2 \\
2+5(n-2)~&\text{for}~n\geq 3
\end{array}
\right.
$$
and call it a day! :)

Comment: Easy: https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C5%2C7%2C12%2C17%2C&language=french&go=Chercher

Comment: Could you please provide some more details on the origin of the problem and the context in which it was presented. By now we had several answers (some more serious than others). The nature of the problem is such that technically such problems are often ill-posed but with enough context they can be interpreted reasonably. But here we do not seem to be in such a case yet.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the sequences continues with $22, 27,32,37, 42$ and so on... starting at $x_1$

$$x_n = (5n-8) + g(n)$$

Where $g(1)=5, g(2)= 3, g(n)=0 \space \forall n>2$